# How do I print out a new file for every 50000 lines in the original file

Tags: node.js, filestream

This is my current code, and its simple. Just read the file one line at a time, each line print out to a new file that's the original name but with _part appended, increase the number every 50000 lines, once done reading run each file name into the function meant to handle the file. However for some reason its just grabbing the ends of each line and printing it out 10000 times (the lines in the original file). It worked at first, I changed some things, it started doing this, and then even though I undid those changes it keeps doing this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
//File containing unprocessed addresses
let fileName = ("Refinitiv_Address_GBR_10000.csv");
//Country we are looking at address of
let country = "UK";

let fileRead;
let fileWrite;
let fileNum = 1;

DivideFile();

async function DivideFile() {
    let lineNum = 0;

    fileWrite = fs.createWriteStream(`./Originals/${fileName.split('.')[0]}_part${fileNum}.${fileName.split('.')[1]}`);

    fileRead = fs.createReadStream(`./Originals/${fileName}`)
        .pipe(csv())
        //Indicate start of reading
        .on('resume', () => {
            console.log("Processing file");
        })
        .on('data', (data) => {
            lineNum++;
            console.log(Object.values(data).toString());
            fs.appendFile(`./Originals/${fileName.split('.')[0]}_part${fileNum}.${fileName.split('.')[1]}`, Object.values(data).toString() + '\n', () => {
                //Nothing to go here at the moment
            });

            if (lineNum == 50000) {
                fileNum++;
                lineNum = 0;
            }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            for (var file in fileNum) {
                RunFunc(`${fileName.split('.')[0]}_part${file}.${fileName.split('.')[1]}`);
            }
        });
}
```

This is a sample of the original data. All are obtained from a public source and not private information

```
,,,,GBR,
"Todd Campus, West of Scotland Science Park,Maryhill Road",GLASGOW,UNITED KINGDOM-NA,G20 0UA,GBR,GBR
,,,,GBR,GBR
,,,,GBR,
"Horsfield Way,, Bredbury Industrial Park",STOCKPORT,CHESHIRE,SK6 2SU,GBR,GBR
"Brunel Way, The Nucleus",Dartford,KENT,DA1 5GA,GBR,
,,,,GBR,
,,,,GBR,
5 New Street Square,London,London,EC4A 3TW,GBR,
"Pentwyn Farm, Huntingdon",,,HR5 3PQ,GBR,GBR
124 Horseferry Road,LONDON,UNITED KINGDOM-NA,SW1P 2TX,GBR,GBR
,,,,GBR,
Unit 700 Fareham Reach Fareham Road,,,,GBR,GBR
"Eastwood House, Glebe Road",CHELMSFORD,ESSEX,CM1 1RS,GBR,GBR
Fineshade Abbey,CORBY,NORTHAMPTONSHIRE,NN17 3BA,GBR,GBR
,,,,,GBR
,,,,GBR,
3 Hempstead Close,,ESSEX,IG9 5JQ,GBR,GBR
,,,,GBR,
,,,,,GBR
,,,,GBR,
,,,,GBR,
25 Farringdon Street,LONDON,UNITED KINGDOM-NA,EC4A 4AB,GBR,GBR
100 Wigmore St,London,X0,,GBR,GBR
,,,,GBR,
```

And this is the first 25 lines, printed out to _part1

```
GBR,GBR
GBR,GBR
,GBR
,GBR
GBR,GBR
,GBR
,GBR
GBR,GBR
,GBR
GBR,GBR
GBR,GBR
,GBR
GBR,GBR
GBR,GBR
GBR,
,GBR
,GBR
GBR,GBR
GBR,
,GBR
GBR,GBR
GBR,GBR
,GBR
,GBR
GBR,GBR
```

I even went and trimmed the code down to just print out each line, and it kept doing this

Comment: Is this for a class?  The Unix `split` command can do this exact thing.

Comment: How can I get NodeJS to run the command? Also its destined for a 5 million line file, and so I'm not sure how well the built in file systems will handle that. Also no, its for work

Comment: [The answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/split-a-file-by-line-and-have-control-over-resulting-files-extension) should give you some ideas.  A 5M line file is trivial and I'd guess that over the last few decades it's been tested a bit.

Comment: Are those UNIX commands? I have little idea how linux works, and also I need the NodeJS script to split it in some way (either by my script or running console commands) as this will be an automated process. Also simply, is there anything in my code that looks off and might cause this, because it was working just fine at first and I have no idea what's causing the change

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but here's basically your code doing it into nice little chunks. You should use the `csv-parse` library not `csv-parser` as you have, and update the file reference at each iteration of the loop. As others mentioned, the `split` unix function would be a good choice for this. I tested this with your sample data in `file.csv`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parse'); // csv-parse not csv-parser
//File containing unprocessed addresses
let fileName = ("file.csv");
//Country we are looking at address of
let country = "UK";

let fileRead;
let fileWrite;
let fileNum = 1;

DivideFile();

async function DivideFile() {
  let lineNum = 0;

  fileWrite = fs.createWriteStream(`./${fileName.split('.')[0]}_part${fileNum}.${fileName.split('.')[1]}`);

  fileRead = fs.createReadStream(`./${fileName}`)
  .pipe(csv())
  //Indicate start of reading
  .on('resume', () => {
    console.log("Processing file");
  })
  .on('data', (data) => {
    lineNum++;
    fileWrite.write(Object.values(data).toString() + '\n');

    if (lineNum === 10) {
      fileNum++;
      fileWrite = fs.createWriteStream(`./${fileName.split('.')[0]}_part${fileNum}.${fileName.split('.')[1]}`);
      lineNum = 0;
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    for (var file in fileNum) {
     // RunFunc(`${fileName.split('.')[0]}_part${file}.${fileName.split('.')[1]}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So its just a matter of the fact that the package I'm using is having issues for some reason? Also thanks to the way my company works, it can take a couple weeks to approve getting even a single package for project. But I'll try to get it passed through so I can try it out